# how to invoke objectForPrimaryKey on my class

Tags: swift, realm

I've got a class with an override for primaryKey as documented.

```
    if let existing = Contact(forPrimaryKey: personR.recordID) {

    }
```

when i do this the compiler says get rid of "forPrimaryKey" :
"Extra argument 'forPrimaryKey' in call"

When i do get rid of it, it regards it as an init and then complains that
"Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument of type 'Int32'"

Any idea how to call this method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if let existing = Contact.objectForPrimaryKey(personR.recordID) {

}
```

Comment: This actually gives an error.
error: 'objectForPrimaryKey' is unavailable: use object construction 'RLMObject(forPrimaryKey:)'
        Contact.objectForPrimaryKey(recordID)
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Realm.RLMObject:258:42: note: 'objectForPrimaryKey' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
  @objc(objectForPrimaryKey:) class func objectForPrimaryKey(primaryKey: AnyObject!) -> Self!

Answer (score 2):

Contact(forPrimaryKey: personR.recordID) actually works i was working on Swift 1.2 on Xcode 6.3 and was seeing strange behavior.

Thanks @Segiddins for the help

Comment: I am seeing a "Cannot find an initializer" still